# Is there a way to play music from an android phone in a from an ipod/iphone dock

Tags: music-player, ios

There are many devices on the market that have a docking station for iphones, ipods and ipads that allow to play the music from the ipod through their speakers, and many time also to control the ipod through the docking station. For me, it's the stereo of my car.

Is there some way (obviously with an adapter) to use those docks to play music stored on an android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you will need a 3.5mm connector to iPod proprietary 40-pin converter. There are some available on eBay here: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/ipod-female-connector (note -- this link is temporary once the items are sold; if someone finds a permalink to a product page please edit my answer and add it).

Comment: Now that you mention the keywords, I've also [found one at Amazon](http://www.amazon.de/Decrescent-Dock-Anschluss-5-mm-Klinkenstecker-Autoradio-Audiokabel/dp/B008I1K6PW/). I also found several more. But most of them (the linked one excluded) show low ratings. Good find!

Comment: note that this will probably not work. My receiver has a dock, it will only interface with some older models. Even though all the models have audio on the same two pins. And what this does, is have the 30pin use only the 2 for audio... which is not a garantee that the device will accept. in fact, if it has honest apple certification, it won't work because apple force that. if it is a chinese knockoff that never paid apple for certification, than it will probably work. Sometimes being a illegal chinese manufacturer has its advantages.

Comment: Some Bose docks require a signal from the iPod/iPhone on one of the pins to turn the dock on, others probably have similar functionality.   I've seen an adapter that claims to solve this; unfortunately, I don't have a link.   I'd suggest looking for an adapter that recognizes this problem and claims to address it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any adapter for Apple's connector. But if you're open to alternatives, maybe I can introduce you to a solution I'm currently using:

On my Android device, I've installed [BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bubbleupnp-upnp-dlna/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). As the name suggests, this app is dealing with DLNA/UPnP: it's a client, a server, and a control point at the same time – which gives you multiple options, provided the "other end" supports DLNA:

- you can access your Android device from the other end, and select the titles (music, movies) you want to stream from it
- you could do the same thing the other way around
- if the "big one" can act as a "media renderer", you can use *BubbleUPnP* to tell it what to play

I lately used it in the last described way: browsing my tablet, selecting a video, and telling my TV to play that – all from the tablet. The first way also worked pretty well: From my TV, I browsed my media gallery, and selected an entire directory of photos to be played as slideshow. Same would of course work for music. And that would even do with my receiver, without turning on the TV.